# child is not shown on Event.DEACTIVATE

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, addchild

I want to achieve this in my game http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2011/03/29/pausing-a-flash-game-or-movie-detecting-its-focus/

everything works fine(game is paused) but the screen is not "drawn" but if I move the mouse over the swf the screen appears

```
private function onDeactivate(e:Event):void {
            pauseGame=true;
            addChild(FocusScreen);
            if(musicOn==true){
                musicCh.stop();
            }
            stage.frameRate = 0;
        }
```

UPDATE: this only occurs if i set stage framerate to 0
this works but I need to set the framerate 0

```
private function onDeactivate(e:Event):void {
                pauseGame=true;
                addChild(FocusScreen);
                if(musicOn==true){
                    musicCh.stop();
                }
            }
```

Comment: showing your code might be a good start

Comment: why does framerate need to be zero? As the tut states, it automatically reduces it to 2 fps when not 'active'

Comment: well that's strange because the frames are not reduced to 2 but it works if I manualy set them

Comment: If you set the frame rate to 0, it seems to imply that the screen should not be updated again. It's going to show 0 frames per second. Since no frame needs to be shown, the screen does not update. So can you explain why you need to set it to 0?

Comment: I need to stop the animations and then resume them. I found this http://www.jasonsturges.com/2012/09/stop-and-play-all-children-within-a-hierarchy-of-movieclips/ the stop part works but the play not

Comment: so I found a fix for the hierarchy play not working: In my animations a have to put play(); on the first frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `e.updateAfterEvent()` after setting stage's frame rate. This forces a single redraw of the stage, after that the stage's framerate set to 0 kicks in, and the stage does not get redrawn anymore until you restore its framerate.

Update: apparently it is a bug in Flash player 11.3 (maybe more of FP11) that wasn't in place with FP10, so the "naked" approach as in the tutorial worked for me when I used a debugger FP10 that comes with FlashDevelop, but didn't work when I have tried it in my FF with FP11.3 installed. So the workaround is as follows: Add a bogus `Sprite` object into your code, do not add it anywhere, it will serve as a recipient of a custom `MouseEvent` event for the sole purpose of calling `updateAfterEvent()`. This worked for me to display a custom DisplayObject that signifies the paused state.

```
private var pausedRecipient:Sprite=new Sprite();
// do not add child so that its listener won't trigger on user input
pausedRecipient.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,uae);
private function uae(e:MouseEvent):void {e.updateAfterEvent();}
private function onDeactivate(e:Event):void {
            pauseGame=true;
            addChild(FocusScreen);
            if(musicOn==true){
                musicCh.stop();
            }
            pausedRecipient.dispatchEvent(
              new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.CLICK,true, true, -1, -1, stage));
            // ^ this does the trick of indirect call of updateAfterEvent()
        }
```

Comment: updateafterevent() is only available as a method of the timerevent, mouseevent and keyboardevent classes

Comment: Hmm. Right. Okay, updating.

Comment: @SeleiLaurentiu By the way, I have managed to break the tutorial movie by pressing Tab. Perhaps activate/deactivate events are just not what's needed.